# How to use single script in stead of two simultaneous scripts in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

friends, I have two scripts. first script has some hotkeys and hotstrings and the second script contains some timer command to activate the specific window when certain time passes. when i paste the codes of second script into the first script then the first script (which contains hotstrings and hotkeys) also stops working. when both the script are run simultaneously then they work perfect. so i want to use one script in stead of two scripts. the codes of first script are like this-

```
!r::
Send, {SHIFT DOWN}
sleep 100
send {F3}
sleep 100
send {SHIFT UP}
sleep 3000 
send tm{ENTER}
sleep 3000
send a
sleep 100
send {ENTER 3}
sleep 100
send c
sleep 100
send nr{F4}
return

!p::
Send, {SHIFT DOWN}{F3}{SHIFT UP}
sleep 3000 
send tm{ENTER}
sleep 3000
send a{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}
sleep 500
send c
sleep 500
send np{F4}
return

!a::
IfWinNotActive, Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer, , WinActivate,    Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer, 
WinWaitActive, Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer, 
Send, {SHIFT DOWN}{F3}{SHIFT UP}
Sleep, 3000
send acli{ENTER}
Sleep, 4000
send {ENTER}
send ^f
sleep 100
send 01.03.2015
sleep 100
send {shiftdown}{tab}{shiftup}
sleep 200
send {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}
return
;there are so many more hotkeys and hotstrings in this script
```

similarly the content of the second script are this-

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, forFinacle, 10000 ; check every 10 seconds
#IfWinActive, Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer
~F4::timeF4:=A_TickCount
~F10::timeF10:=A_TickCount

forFinacle:
If (A_TickCount-timeF4 > 800000) && (A_TickCount-timeF10 > 800000)
{
WinActivate Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer 
Send {F4}
timeF4:=A_TickCount
}
return
```

So i want the content of both the scripts into one script and that script should work perfectly. Please help me. thanks a lot.

Comment: When I have run into issues with scripts not combining, it has often been the problem of an omitted `return`. Another note: I used `#include %A_ScriptDir%\Acronyms.ahk' to keep things in two files that run at once. Where the Acronyms.ahk is my set of text expansions and the root file has my timers.

Answer (score 0):

> Keeps a script permanently running (that is, until the user closes it
>   or ExitApp is encountered).
>
> **#Persistent**
>
> If this directive is present anywhere in the script, that script will
>   stay running after the auto-execute section (top part of the script)
>   completes. This is useful in cases where a script contains timers
>   and/or custom menu items but not hotkeys, hotstrings, or any use of
>   OnMessage() or Gui.
>
> If this directive is added to an existing script, you might want to
>   change some or all occurrences of Exit to be ExitApp. This is because
>   Exit will not terminate a persistent script; it terminates only the
>   current thread.
>
> In v1.0.16+, this directive also makes a script single-instance. To
>   override this or change the way single-instance behaves, see
>
> #SingleInstance.
>
> **#SingleInstance**
>
> Determines whether a script is allowed to run again when it is already
>   running.
>
> #SingleInstance [force|ignore|off]

Comment: Dear @SalvoF, thanks for your kind reply. But i know about the directives. my problem is not directive, my problem is i want to use single script in stead of the different scripts. and when i try to combine the contents of both the scripts then the combined script does not work at all. so kindly tell me any way to use the content of two scripts into one script. thanks a lot sir.

Comment: Do you mean you have found an alternative for such directive, removed it from that macro and tried again?

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure to use an `#IfWinActive` statement after you have defined context-specific hotkeys, otherwise all following hotkeys will require the previously defined context in order to execute.

For example, if you place that second block of code at the beginning of your entire consolidated script, the context for all hotkeys would be `#IfWinActive, Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer` until a different directive or blank `#IfWinActive` directive is encountered.

As a general matter of avoiding cut&paste errors and other annoying issues--for example moving a section of hotkey code from one location in a big script to another location--I tend to use `#IfWinActive` statements liberally and always keep a blank one after each section, as well as at the end of the file (due to documented issues with the original implementation).